# Compare data between two tables with in single database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My requirement to compare two table data with in one database and stored the uncommon data in separate table named relation data within same database.

How to compare this tables data?

To compare is their any tools and can we stored uncommon  data in separately table using any tool?
i forgot to tell one thing that two tables having same data but different column names that means for example first table having 20 columns and 2 and table having 50 columns but in that 4 columns are matched data with different number of rows and different column names in each table.based on these columns data matching i need to find rows and stored into another table

Comment: The tool is called `SQL`. You should show us at least the schema of your tables.

Comment: i guese you want something like `INSERT INTO sep_table  (SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE NOT IN (SELECT ids FROM other_table)` or something like `INSTERT INTO sep_table (SELECT .. JOIN WHERE first.col<>second.col)` Cant be more specific becuase your question is not really concrete..

Comment: what actually you wanted to achieve? is two table contain same data??

Comment: Post your tables structure, sample data and expected results. Are both tables same or they just have common columns? What is criteria for common/uncommon data?

Comment: Relevant columns for matching: 
informationid, company, city, state


OUTPUT 
---------
new table called: relationdata

inforamtionid (key from information table)
customerid (key from customer table)

Comment: while i check manually the data having some rows are same, some are different and some rows are not in another table this data i want to stored in another table called realation

Comment: sorry every one i forgot to tell one thing that two tables having same data but different column names that means for example first table having 20 columns and 2 and table having 50 columns but in that 4 columns are matched data with different number of rows and different column names in each table.based on these columns data matching i need to find rows and stored into another table.

Comment: first table rows are 2000 and second table data rows are 5000

Comment: hi one of friend given this solution 
foreach row in customer(which is not in customers)
 {
  > search for city match + first few letters
  > if the match is accurate > put the matching customerid + informationid  in the informationrelationtable.
}   but i didnt understood this can any one help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, I think its work

```
insert into relational(r1,r2,r3,....rn)
(select s1,s2,s3,...sn from 
  information info where info.informationcity not in (select customercity from customer)
   and info.informationstate not in (select customerstate from customer) )
```

Comment: i had one doubt that i need to create relational table before or it will automatically create? if i need to create what coluns i have to give?

Comment: you need create that one before executing the above query and what columns you want to take from information table those should be given in that insert statement and those should be in relational table with different names also applicable but data types should be same

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to writing a SQL script, you could copy the entire results from both tables to a .csv file and then use win merge to compare the two:

http://winmerge.org/downloads/

I have used this technique in the past when comparing mass amounts of data and it has worked quite well.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished in t-sql with not a lot of effort. However in your question you were asking for a tool to accomplish this. If you are simply looking to purchase a tool to do this, at my job, we use the Redgate tools for deploying code from test to production, and I believe if you were a little creative you could get the [SQL Data Compare Tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do what you are asking for.

[image: selecting the tables and seeing the differences]

If you select and compare these two tables, it will generate a change script from one to the other. If you only take the changes from one, save off the script, then come back, click on the arrow and take only the changes from the source the other way, you should have the uncommon attributes.

Comment: hi thank you for solution, After comprising two table with same database it's not showing any check boxes

Comment: please see my screenshot attached to the question

Comment: If you right click and select choose comparison key, it will prompt you with a menu of all of the datbes that are being compared. In the comparison key column, it will let you choose how to compare the tables. [For Example](http://i.imgur.com/0v4E1qf.png). Does that help?

Comment: Hi please find my another screen shot

Comment: Hi when right click the above comparison is happened but which i need to compare tables are not having checkbox selection and i select the columns and close the button but i didn't get any result

Comment: So you see where it says not set? You went into that area and selected the column you want to match on? If you do that, it will generate the script needed to make table a like table b. I have a screen shot in my earlier comment of me doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you both tables have the same structure
Quick and dirty?

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 AS OriginTable, *
FROM OriginTable1
UNION SELECT 2 AS  OriginTable, *
FROM OriginTable2
)
SELECT {put here the list of all your columns}
INTO [YourDeltaTable]
FROM cte
GROUP BY {put here the list of all your columns} 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query for inserting data into target table by retrieving data from multiple tables

```
insert into TargetTable(list_of_columns)
(select list of columns from 
  Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 
on (t1.common_column != t2.common_column))
```

The src column list count and target column list count should be equal

Comment: hi i tried this before my problem is both tables not having one columns i.e columns names are totally different and also list count and target column list count is not equal

Comment: Can you please let me know the how many columns in source and how many columns in target

Comment: one table 52 columns and another table 25 columns only two columns data are similar those are city and state but columns titles(names) are different like (table one having customercity and another table informationcity)

Comment: @stpdevi, while joining the tables, the column names are may not be similar but the data in the both columns should be equal.

Comment: @stpdevi can u please tell me the target table name, source table names

Comment: @stpdevi, so u want to get data from information table which not in customer table then insert that data into customer table right?

Comment: @stpdevi if that is situation u can use merge statement to insert the data into customer table by taking from information table. I will give the example if that is the requirement

Comment: no i want to get data from information table which not in customer table then insert that data into another new table called relational table

Comment: @stpdevi , try the below query what i posted

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple example that assumes your table structures are the same

```
DECLARE @a table (
   val char(1)
);

DECLARE @b table (
   val char(1)
);

INSERT INTO @a (val)
  VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C');


INSERT INTO @b (val)
  VALUES ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E');

DECLARE @mismatches table (
   val char(1)
);

INSERT INTO @mismatches (val)
SELECT val -- All those from @a
FROM   @a
EXCEPT     -- Where not in @b
SELECT val
FROM   @b;

INSERT INTO @mismatches (val)
SELECT val -- All those from @a
FROM   @b
EXCEPT     -- Where not in @b
SELECT val
FROM   @a;

SELECT *
FROM   @mismatches
```